# DB migrate problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have just updated by application and db using `rake db:migrate`. However, I am encountering an error:

```
Migrating to CreateSavedBoards (20110111184104)
==  CreateSavedBoards: migrating ==============================================
-- drop_table(:boards)
  SQL (0.0ms)   Mysql::Error: Unknown table 'boards': DROP TABLE `boards`
rake aborted!
An error has occurred, all later migrations canceled:

Mysql::Error: Unknown table 'boards': DROP TABLE `boards`

(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Migration file causing the error?

```
class CreateBoardCategoriesSavedboards < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :board_categories_boards, :id => false do |t|
      t.integer :board_category_id
      t.integer :board_id
    end

    add_index :board_categories_boards, [:board_category_id, :board_id], :name => "bcb_board_category_id_board_id"
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :board_categories_boards
  end
end
```

This is the model for the Boards.

```
class Board < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :image, :foreign_key => 'image'
  belongs_to :clip, :foreign_key => 'clip'
  has_and_belongs_to_many :categories, :class_name => 'BoardCategory', :foreign_key => 'board_id'
  has_many :comments, :as => :commentable
  set_table_name "savedboards"
end
```

I am thinking that the error comes from Rails thinking that there is a `boards` table because the the `board_id` in the migration file above.

Am I right in thinking that this may be causing the migration to fail and what can I do about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The migration's output is showing that `drop_table :boards` is happening, but it doesn't appear in your migration. Perhaps it is an earlier migration that is attempting to drop the `boards` table?

Comment: exactly and it seems the old migration id CreateSavedBoards